# Describe a strategy that lets you win this game of common divisors every time

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I have this question in one of my assignments of a course(MIT 6042) that I am pursuing online. Question is as follows:

> Here is a very, very fun game. We start with two distinct, positive
>   integers written on a blackboard. Call them x and y. You and I now
>   take turns. (I’ll let you decide who goes first.) On each player’s
>   turn, he or she must write a new positive integer on the board that is
>   a common divisor of two numbers that are already there. If a player
>   can not play, then he or she loses. For example, suppose that 12 and
>   15 are on the board initially. Your first play can be 3 or 1. Then I
>   play 3 or 1, whichever one you did not play. Then you can not play, so
>   you lose.
>
> (a) [6 pts] Show that every number on the board at the end of the game
>   is either x, y, or a positive divisor of gcd(x, y).
>
> (b) [6 pts] Show that every positive divisor of gcd(x, y) is on the
>   board at the end of the game.
>
> (c) [6 pts] Describe a strategy that lets you win this game every
>   time.

I was able to solve part (a) as game involves writing only common divisors of `x` and `y` on the board, and gcd(x,y) is the smallest positive linear combination of `x` and `y` and thus can be expressed as `sx+ty`. Further, a common divisor of `x` and `y` divides all linear combinations of `x` and `y` and thus divides gcd(x,y).

Part(b) was rather trivial I suppose, though I am not sure, as game involves writing all common divisors of `x` and `y` and they divide gcd(x,y) as well as proved in part(a).

Main issue is with part (c). Solution I proposed is that if number of common divisors of `x` and `y` is even then let the other player start the game and if it is odd then I should start the game. However this solution seems too trivial as well and I suppose they wouldn't put it in the assignment if it was that simple.

Can anyone tell if there is anything wrong with any of my solutions and if there is a more refined solution to part(c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, your answer to part (c) is correct. However, it can be simplified and expressed more nicely: The number of divisors of a natural number $n$ is odd if and only if $n$ is a perfect square (because all divisors $\ne\sqrt n$ come in pairs).
Therefore, your winning strategy consists in deciding who makes the first move based on whether or not $\gcd(x,y)$ is a perfect square.

Comment: Thanks. Its a really important fact.